# Place border in a 100% height and width div - right and bottom border outside

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I'm using Firefox and want to create a div with height and width 100% and a white border with 10px. The right and bottom part of the border seems outside the div and body.

https://jsfiddle.net/tob6g805/

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ffb0a3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div-with-border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

A workaround was to add border right and bottom and to decrease the width and height of the div... but this becomes especially problematic when resizing the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/1wtjkybm/

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ffb0a3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div-with-border {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px;
  border-bottom: 100px;
  border-right: 100px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
>   element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
>   has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
>   to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen. This
>   means that when you set width and height, you have to adjust the value
>   you give to allow for any border or padding that may be added.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

There's a CSS property called `box-sizing` which allows you to adjust this property. Adding `box-sizing: border-box` to `.div-with-border` should fix this for you!

Take a look at the link above. They have a live example that demonstrates `box-sizing`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using flexbox

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body,
html,
html * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

  body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ffb0a3;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
  }

  .div-with-border {

    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 10px;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:7vw;
    font-family:Open Sans;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#d46a58;
  }
```

Also, always do:

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

in the `<head>` tag.